# UDP packets in wrong order with simple Kubernetes setup

Tags: kubernetes, networking, udp

I am experiencing UDP packets coming out of my pods in a wrong order.

When using tshark inside a pod's container (through the kubernetes dashboard and using "exec") on the container `eth0` interface :

- I see that some UDP packets are sent in bad order (example: 1-2-**10-11-12**-3-4-5-6-7...).
- This happens sporadically.
- This is problematic since these packets are carrying order dependent information.

For instance, when using an `ffmpeg` command inside one of my pod to send a video file via UDP to a  service I am experiencing the problem. Using another program instead of `ffmpeg` I am still experiencing the same issue. It doesn't seem to come from the application itself.

The same applications (`ffmpeg`, custom application, ...) are working fine outside of the cluster with docker or when running the binaries. No UDP packets are sent in the wrong order here.

When I try to send the UDP packets from one container to another in the same pod, I am still experiencing the same issue.

I tried on 4 different kind of machines/setups with similar results:

- 2 x Intel® NUC Kit NUC8i7BEH (Intel Core i7-8559U @ 2.70GHz, 32GB ram):

  - deloyed with terraform
  - Rke cluster (container based)
  - container runtime: dockerd
- 2 x Intel® NUC Kit NUC8i7BEH (Intel Core i7-8559U @ 2.70GHz, 32GB ram):

  - deployed with kubadm
  - network plugin (cni): calico
  - container runtime: crio
- 3 x Old supermicro blade servers (Pentium 4 3Ghz, 2GB ram each):

  - deployed with kubadm
  - network plugin (cni): calico
  - container runtime: containerd
- 3 x VMs (12 cores each of a Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 5218R CPU @ 2.10GHz):

  - deployed with kubadm
  - network plugin (cni): calico
  - container runtime: crio

All setups are using wired Ethernet connection.

What should I do to guarantee that my UDP packets will always be sent in the right order when coming out of my containers when in Kubernetes? Is there a networking configuration that needs to be made to the cluster ?

Edit:
Here is a simple kubernetes config that reproduces the issue:

We have two pods using ffmpeg, one sending the signal and the other one receiving.

Here is the sender's config:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: ffmpeg-stream
  labels:
    app: ffmpeg-stream
spec:
  containers:
    - name: ffmpeg-record
      securityContext:
        privileged: true
      image: linuxserver/ffmpeg
      command: ["ffmpeg"]
      args: ["-re", "-f", "lavfi", "-i", "nullsrc=s=1280x720", "-filter_complex", "geq=random(1)*255:128:128;aevalsrc=-2+random(0)", "-b:v", "20M", "-c:v", "libx264", "-preset", "ultrafast", "-f", "mpegts", "udp://ffmpeg-record:26500?pkt_size=1316"]
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: "2Gi"
          cpu: 6
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /data/discontinuity
          name: data
          subPath: discontinuity
  volumes:
  - name: data
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: nfs
```

Here is the receiver's config:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: ffmpeg-record
  labels:
    app: ffmpeg-record
spec:
  containers:
    - name: ffmpeg-record
      securityContext:
        privileged: true
      image: linuxserver/ffmpeg
      command: ["ffmpeg"]
      args: ["-i", "udp://localhost:1234", "-c:v", "copy", "-c:a", "copy", "-sn", "test.ts"]
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: "1Gi"
          cpu: 3
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /data/discontinuity
          name: data
          subPath: discontinuity
  volumes:
  - name: data
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: nfs

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ffmpeg-record
spec:
  selector:
    app: ffmpeg-record
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - port: 26500
    targetPort: 1234
    protocol: UDP
```

Comment: UDP has no guarantees. TCP will guarantee in-order delivery of data to an application, but UDP has nothing like that. UDP datagrams (not packets) are simply sent, and they may be dropped, out of order etc. You would need to implement an application-layer protocol to deal with this for UDP, or you use TCP.

Comment: I agree, it is normal for UDP to have losses. However in my case the UDP datagrams are transmitted in a local network that should not lose packets : when using this same network to transmit the same stream in the same conditions but whithout kubernetes there are no losses.

Comment: How do you run the pod, could you show the manifest?

Comment: You seem to want to have your cake and eat it too. If you use UDP, expect losses and out of order delivery. You cannot complain of such because you should already expect it.

Comment: I added the manifest files to my post for more context.

Answer (score 1):

> What should I do to guarantee that my UDP packets will always be sent in the right order

Strictly speaking, you cannot. What I think you are saying is you really want them to **arrive** in the same order. (Sending in the wrong order is probably a great way to have them arrive out of order...)

Packets get lost, arrive out of order. TCP has many layers of features to handle these problems and deliver a data stream to the recipient that is properly ordered.

UDP will simply hand the arriving data to the receiver. Based on what you are seeing on the sending site, the network stack is faithful the liberalities of UDP even when sending.

You didn't provide any code, so I don't think you can get a solution from here.

But historically, the solution would be to send over UDP only one item, then wait for a response that confirms, and then send the second... if memory serves me correctly, this was what TFTP (not FTP) did. The tradeoffs are pretty obvious, and many of the replacement protocols used a TCP-based solution.

Comment: I wrote "sent" and not "arrive" for a reason: I observed directly in the container hosting the application sending udp that the datagrams were already out of order (while I am pretty sure the sending apps do send packets in the proper order). I agree on the fact that I cannot guarantee that my UDP datagrams are sent in the right order, but the misordering happens way too frequently. As I said, while using the same applications and network configs but without kubernetes I do not suffer any packet misorder (or almost). My issue here is that passing through kubernetes causes many order problems.

Comment: And I am aware that there are ways to make sure the UDP datagrams are sent without flaws: I am using the SRT protocol as an input of my applications.

Comment: I agree, but without looking thru every layer of the data flow, and the source, you might not be able to find the cause. Historically sending UDP has been ordered because of what would now be legacy aspects of the architecture. Most of the older libraries I've lived with presented the endpoint as a file descriptor, so data made its way down to the wire almost like a row of rail-cars. I'm open to the idea that at almost every layer, this assumption might not hold anymore.